# Specflow Html Report in NetCore

Tags: .net-core, specflow

is there any way to get an html report when running Specflow on NetCore 3? 
I am running specflow + with nunitRunner.
I know there was reporting feature in Specflow but it seems it is not available for NetCore.

Comment: Why do you think, that it doesn't work in .NET Core?

Comment: Because I read the discussion in the github repo and the developers mentioned that they had to extract the reports feature into a separate asset/repository in order to make specflow work on netCore. Do you know something different? are you generating html specflow reports on dotnet?

Comment: Can you share this github thread? The official [docs](https://specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-Runner-Profiles/#Report/) say that you can use the runner profile with `dotnet test` and declare the `report` element inside profile

Comment: I think it is this: https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/1036, but beyond what you mention about the documentation, were you able to make it run?